# Finding the first significant figure of difference between two very similar values

Tags: r, comparison, significant-digits

I'm trying to reproduce the computations that led to a data set `data.ref`. I'd like to test how well my current implementation does by comparing the reference data to my computed results, `data.my`. Since each column of the data should have comparable magnitudes within the column, but not necessarily between columns, I've been looking at

```
(data.ref - data.my) / data.ref
```

to put errors on a comparable scale. However, since the data is ultimately going to be rounded off, what I'd really like to do is just run a quick and dirty check of how many significant figures worth of agreement the data has. That is, since I expect `data.ref` and `data.my` to be quite close to each other, I'd like the answer the question: **what is the first significant figure at which each pair of corresponding entries differs?**

Is there an R function that does this?

Answer (score 1):

`ceiling(log10(abs(data.ref, data.my)))` seems to do the trick.

Example:

```
> data.my <- c(20, 30, 32, 32.01, 32.012)
> data.ref <- rep(32, length(data.my))
> ceiling(log10(abs(data.my - data.ref)))
[1]    2    1 -Inf   -2   -1
```